# SQL query combine select statements

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have SQL query like follow:

```
SELECT *r1.val, r2.prevVal
FROM (Select statement) AS r1,
(Select statement) AS r2
WHERE 
r1.object_id = r2.object_id
```

It work, problem is, when `r2` select statement return nothing, therefore, whole statement return nothing, because it can't execute `r1.object_id = r2.object_id`.

How could I reproduce the same statement, which will output values, if there are values in select statement `r1`, and no values in select statement `r2`? So I can access value `r1.val`.

Comment: Are you calling object_id from both of the select statements? If not you will get an error

Comment: You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992. You should not use that anymore. Use explicit joins instead: `from r1 inner join r2 on ...` when you want an inner join or `from r1 left outer join r2 on ...` when you want an outer join. (You are using an inner join, but really want to use an outer join here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT Join like:

```
SELECT *r1.val, r2.prevVal
FROM (Select statement) AS r1
LEFT JOIN (Select statement) AS r2 ON r1.object_id = r2.object_id    ---------------------Formatted as code
```